# How to save Parse objects in background from an iOS app that is in background?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have an iOS app that collects location information in background and pushes it to Parse. While pushing, I check for reachability of **Parse.com**. If it is reachable, I use `saveInBackground`, else I use `saveEventually`. Here is the sequence of events:

1. Start the app
2. Put it in background by pushing home button.
3. Move around
4. Check for updates in Parse.

What I find is that the updates are not pushed ( not visible in the Parse browser) when the app is in background. However, as soon I click to get the app in foreground, the updates happen and I see them on the web. I have checked that I have the correct permissions (always get location updates) in plist and I do see that the location updates are actually received in my app's memory, but they seem to be waiting in the Parse push queue to get out on the network. The whole time , while the app is in the background or foreground, I am connected to the network.

In my situation, it is likely that the user may not click the app for a long time, but I do need locations in Parse backend for my backend logic. How do I get the updates pushed while in background? I have searched and looked at AnyPic code, but it is not applicable for recent iOS since  in recent iOS, we need to use `NSURL` for background pushes.

Here is the code-segment of what I am doing. I am using dispatch_async with beginBackgroundtask.

```
var backgroundTaskId: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier!
if(Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()) {

            // Request a background execution task to allow us to finish uploading the location even if the app is backgrounded
            self.backgroundTaskId = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskId)
            }

            NSLog("Requested background expiration task with id \(self.backgroundTaskId) for writing:\(object)")


            // Dispatch async with network connected and then backgrounding the task currently stops
            // on-going updates which resume when the task is brought into foreground again.
            // This behaviour is of saveInBackground and not of iOS related stuff as it also happens
            // without dispatch async and background task ID. See:
            // See my question:
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427082/how-to-save-parse-objects-in-background-from-an-ios-app-that-is-in-background
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
      object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if(succeeded) {

                            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskId)
            }
        else
            {
                object.saveEventually()
                  UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskId)        }

            })    // saveInBackground
            })    // dispatch_async
        }
        else  // No Network
        {
            object.saveEventually()     
        }
```

Comment: Thanks David for the edit, I will adhere to it in future questions.

Comment: Are you using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` and if so, are you calling `endBackgroundTask` too soon? Make sure you are calling `endBackgroundTask` *inside*, and at the end of, the `saveInBackgroundWithBlock`'s block.

Comment: Examined the code, added it to the question. beginbBackgroundTaskWithExp.. was used. So we need to look elsewhere..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push updates in the background, you will need to enable Background Modes. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial) that should help you.

Comment: I added my code to the question, I seem to be doing things described in the tutorial..